# Understanding Borel-Cantelli in an "asymptotic" setting

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $X_1(p),...,X_j(p),\dots$ be a sequence of random variables that depend on a parameter $1\le p \le \infty$. Suppose that the $n$-th variable satisfies $Pr [X_n>t] < c_n/p^n$ for some constant that depends on $n$ (but not $p$).

Does it follow by the Borel-Cantelli lemma that only finitely many of the $X_n$ can be greater than $t$, **as $p\to\infty$?**

I think the answer is **no**, since taking $c_n=n^n$ means $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n/p^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n/p)^n$, where for a particular $p$, there is always an $n$ such that $(n/p)\ge 1$.

Is there another argument that can be made to prove a Borel-Cantelli-like statement? Because on the other hand, for any finite $n$, you can always choose a $p$ such that $(n/p)<1$...